# getting Jcomponent from other class changes frame size

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

Hello I am try to get jcomponent from other class.the components are displaying but my frame size changes.

**Example.java**

```
public class Example extends JFrame{

  static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  static A a = new A();
  static B b = new B();
  static JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();   
  static String value;

     Example(){
        setSize(400, 400);
        combo.setBounds(450, 140, 50, 20);
        combo.addItem("");
        combo.addItem("a");
        combo.addItem("b");
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                value = (String) combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(value.equals("a")){
                    panel.add(a.getLabel());
                    panel.remove(b.getLabel());
                    add(panel);
                    pack(); 
                }else if(value.equals("b")){
                    panel.add(b.getLabel());
                    panel.remove(a.getLabel());
                    add(panel);
                    pack();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(combo);
        this.add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

**A.java**

```
public class A extends JFrame{

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JLabel lab = new JLabel("Text");

  A(){
      lab.setBounds(280, 25, 150, 50);
      lab.setVisible(true);
      panel.add(lab);
      add(panel);
  }
  public  JLabel getLabel(){
    return lab;
  }
}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton lab = new JButton("Hello");

    B(){
       lab.setBounds(380, 25, 250, 50);
       lab.setVisible(true);
       panel.add(lab);
       add(panel);
    }
    public JButton getLabel(){
       return lab;  
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] agrs) {
    Example ex = new Example();
    ex.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

when I run frame open as defined size but when I select **a** from combo box the frame size decreases any suggestion so as screen size remain same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to solve this is to get rid of `pack()` and subsitute `revalidate()` and `repaint`:

```
add(panel);
revalidate();
repaint();
// pack();
```

- `revalidate` tells the layout managers to re-lay out their components.
- `repaint` requests that the component be repainted, especially "dirty" regions
- `pack` tells the window to re-lay out all components and resize to the optimal size.

Much better would be to use a CardLayout, and the window and component size will remain constant, big enough to fit the largest component. ... and avoid all use of null layouts.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Example2 extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] COMBO_TEXTS = {"", "a", "b"};
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private DefaultComboBoxModel<String > comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(COMBO_TEXTS);
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

   public Example2() {
      setLayout(cardLayout);
      ComboListener comboListener = new ComboListener();

      JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
      combo.addActionListener(comboListener);;
      JPanel panelBlank = new JPanel();
      panelBlank.add(combo);

      JPanel panelWithText = new JPanel();
      combo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
      combo.addActionListener(comboListener);;
      panelWithText = new JPanel();
      panelWithText.add(combo);
      panelWithText.add(new JLabel("Text"));

      JPanel panelWithButton = new JPanel();
      combo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
      combo.addActionListener(comboListener);;
      panelWithButton = new JPanel();
      panelWithButton.add(combo);
      panelWithButton.add(new JButton("Hello"));

      add(panelBlank, COMBO_TEXTS[0]);
      add(panelWithText, COMBO_TEXTS[1]);
      add(panelWithButton, COMBO_TEXTS[2]);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class ComboListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JComboBox<String> combo = (JComboBox<String>)e.getSource();
         String item = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
         cardLayout.show(Example2.this, item);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Example2 mainPanel = new Example2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

This simplifies things and makes it harder to shoot yourself in the foot. So rather than this:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value = (String) combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(value.equals("a")){
                panel.add(a.getLabel());
                panel.remove(b.getLabel());
                // add(panel);
                // pack();
            }else if(value.equals("b")){
                panel.add(b.getLabel());
                panel.remove(a.getLabel());
                // add(panel);
                // pack();
            }
            add(panel);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
```

Your ActionListener's actionPerformed method is just this:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JComboBox<String> combo = (JComboBox<String>)e.getSource();
     String item = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
     cardLayout.show(Example2.this, item);
  }
```

---

For more on the CardLayout, its uses and functionality, please check out the [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). But in a nutshell, it automates the process of swapping "views" in a GUI, making it much harder to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: that worked!! thanks..but what does cardlayout is for? and sorry to ask what is this 'dirty' region.

Comment: @Mohit: For more on the CardLayout, its uses and functionality, please check out the [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). But in a nutshell, it automates the process of swapping "views" in a GUI, making it much harder to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `revalidate()` instead of `pack()`;  `pack()` automatically resizes your frame in order to fit the subcomponents:

javadoc for pack():

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method.