# Enumerating all controls on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am quite new to Java and am trying to set the visible property to false for all JPanels
on my JFrame (frame.)

When I execute the following, It returns null to console:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    for (Component c : frame.getComponents()) {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) { 
            ((JPanel)c).setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    panelDispatch.setVisible(true);
    panelDispatch.requestFocus();
}
```

What I want it to do is set all the panels visibility to false then
set the selected panels visibility to true.
3 JPanels are added to frame.

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you get error ? or just "null" text in console ?

Comment: Adem: Just null text.  I wasn't setting the name field for my panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why you're seeing null, and I'm not sure in what way you're seeing it, a NullPointerException perhaps, but I do know that you appear to be removing the JFrame's contentPane, glassPane and rootPane inadvertently, a dangerous thing to do. Instead just use a CardLayout that should allow you to easily and simply swap your GUI views as this is exactly what CardLayout was built for. Please check out the [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information.

---

**Edit**
For examples of CardLayout-using GUI's, please check out:

- [getting Jcomponent from other class changes frame size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436726/522444)
- [Java CardLayout Main Menu Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893078/java-cardlayout-main-menu-problem/6893133#6893133)
- [Change size of JPanel using CardLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414177/change-size-of-jpanel-using-cardlayout/5414770#5414770)
- [Java CardLayout JPanel moves up, when second JPanel added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695387/java-cardlayout-jpanel-moves-up-when-second-jpanel-added/5695659#5695659)
- [Java swing; How to toggle panel's visibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600051/java-swing-how-to-toggle-panels-visibility/5600247#5600247)
- [Clear components of JFrame and add new componets on the same JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027849/clear-components-of-jframe-and-add-new-componets-on-the-same-jframe/8027858#8027858)
- [gui multiple frames switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668132/gui-multiple-frames-switch/5670370#5670370)
- [JLabel displaying countdown, java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811064/jlabel-displaying-countdown-java/6811186#6811186)

This one is unusual in that it uses a CardLayout and has one panel fading into the other panel:

- [CardLayout showing two panels, flashing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275584/522444).

Comment: 1+, CardLayout would be my suggestion as well.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels A bit confusing for me but I will start looking into all of this.  Thank you for all the info!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I can't thank you enough for the links.  TabDemo is EXACTLY how I want my app to look/act.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Components are added to a `ContentPane` of a `JFrame` rather than the `RootPane`. You're seeing `null` displayed to the console as you probably havent set the [name property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName-java.lang.String-) of the component

```
for (Component c : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
```

Comment: Reimeus: That worked perfectly.  Simple replacement.  Thank you.

Comment: So you're advocating that the OP do this over use of a CardLayout? If so, why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't think that he's suggesting I use this over your suggestion.  From what I see he is showing me how to get the name of the components.